# How to make a PATH variable availailable to Apache? (OSX Lion)

Tags: php, python, macos, apache

I have a Python script that is using MySQLdb on OSX Lion. To get MySQLdb to work, I had to add

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to my ~/.bash_profile. The python script, when executed from the command line, works just fine.

When I try executing the same python script from a PHP script using the exec() function, the python script is unable to locate the library path. Here's the err msg from the Apache log:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm assuming this is a user issue though I'm unclear on how to fix it.

Where should I put this path so that it will be globally available to all scripts and users on my machine? (well at least, to Apache and Root)

Comment: Some more info/clarification: If I run python from terminal as a normal, non-root user, "import MySQLdb" works; if I sudo and try the same, I get the error. Therefore the problem must be one of scope for the user. I would like to solve this outside of Python by exporting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in the right place to be available to all users, but I don't know where/how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: creating a soft link did the trick:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

This solution was taken from comments on [this post](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/). Perhaps this solution will help another struggling with MySQLdb on OSX.

Though I'm still not clear on why it worked on one user and not another - or, rather, to which file the above mentioned export should have been saved in order to make it available to all. Any explanation on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Apache doesn't read .bash_profile, so it doesn't pick up the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to modify sys.path array. It initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: No, there is a solution outside of python. I had this same code working on another dev machine (Snow Leopard). I just need some help w/users/permissions in UNIX...

Answer (score 0):

For Apache you can add PYTHONPATH entry to the EnvironmentVariables section in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` that will make it available to anything Apache runs. See `man launchd.plist` for details.

For root you can add an export PYTHONPATH to `/etc/profile` which will make it available to all sh and bash login shells. See `man bash` for details.